# Flink Yarn infinite restart on task failure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running flink streaming job on AWS yarn cluster with below configuration

Master Node - 1, Core Node - 1, Task Nodes - 3

And I enabled

```
jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy: region
```

As one of my task nodes are failing and trying to restart at region level (in my case at task node level) and I enabled the restart strategy as fixedDelayrestart with 5 attempts of 5 minutes delay and my checkpoints are disabled.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql2Le.png)

If you see the image it is restarting more than expected.

Can anybody help me understand why does it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has a section about the *"Restart Pipelined Region Failover Strategy"* [1]. The bottom line is, if you have a streaming job with an operator that physically partitions the stream, such as `keyBy`, all tasks will end up being in the same region, and therefore all tasks will be restarted as a whole. For batch jobs, you need to configure the `ExecutionMode` [2] to be `BATCH` or `BATCH_FORCED`.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#restart-pipelined-region-failover-strategy

[2] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionMode.html